# How to write complex query with mysql join with tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, inner-join

I have tables

`Tasks- id,name`

then i have

`userTasks id , task_id , user_id`

and

`User - id , name`

Suppose i have 10 tasks in task table and out of those i have 3 tasks in `userTask` table

I want query like this

`Select task.id , task.name , STATUS (if(presentInUserTasks),1,0) FROM  whatever`

the STATUS word should `1` if that task id is present in usertasks table for that userid otherwise it should be `0`

So that i am able to find which of those tasks are alreadu in userTask table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the `EXISTS` keyword:

```
SELECT tasks.id, tasks.name, 
    IF(EXISTS(SELECT id 
              FROM userTasks 
              WHERE userTasks.task_id = tasks.id 
              AND userTasks.user_id = @that_user_id)
       ,1,0) AS STATUS
FROM tasks
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT  b.id, 
        b.name, 
        IF(coalesce(c.Task_ID, -1) = -1, 0, 1) `Status`
FROM    `User` a 
            CROSS JOIN `Task` b
            LEFT JOIN UserTask c
                ON a.ID = c.user_ID AND
                   b.ID = c.Task_ID
Where  a.id = 1
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a22d0/7

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select T.id , T.name , 
       case when  u.task_id is not null then 1 else 0 end as STATUS 
from 
Tasks T left outer join usertasks U
on T.id=u.task_id
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
SELECT t.id,t.name, 
CASE WHEN ut.task_id IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE '1' END
FROM Tasks t
LEFT JOIN UserTask ut ON ut.task_id = t.id
```

Comment: I tried but it only returns where staus =1 but i want all the results from tasks table but the results which are in userTasks should have STATUS =1 FOR others it should be 0

Comment: I think u didn't match userid on usertasks and also u didn't wrote  STATUS  field name